# Can't select when I use WHERE and "=" in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql like this, the numbers and words in mysql is stroed as "text"

```
+---------+----------+
| numbers | words    |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | help     |
| 2       | helper   |
| 3       | helped   |
+---------+----------+
```

but the sentence

```
SELECT * FROM Talbe(just refer the talename) WHERE words='help'
```

doesn't return any results, I don't konw why and where I am wrong?
and there are no any blanks before and behind 'help' in the talbe

Comment: is the name of the table `Table`? If so escape it using `s

Comment: You are probably ignoring error messages or not fetching them.

Comment: I've seen you've just edited the question to remove all traces of real code.

Comment: Do you get error messages at all? No one can replicate your issue, you *have* to be more descriptive.

Comment: I use php to get the result $reslt=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Talbe(just refer the talename) WHERE words='help'");

Comment: btw, don't use mysql_* functions, they're depreciated. Prefer use something like PDO or prepared statements.

Comment: I find the reason, in the talbe, there is a newline at the end of the word 'help' or 'helped', and how can I write the select sentence or do something else?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM Table AS t WHERE t.words='help'
```

Try using alias so it will work. Table is a reserved keyword change the name of your table to something else

```
SELECT * FROM myable AS t WHERE t.words='help
```

Another way is escaping

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE words='help'
```

But i would recommend changing the table name and using aliases

Comment: better escape Table as using `

Comment: the talbename is not Talbe, I just use Table to refer the name

Comment: Creating an alias does not make `Table` stop being a reserved keyword.

Comment: that's why i said `i would recommend changing the table name and using aliases`

Answer (score 2):

If MySQL does not throw any error on Your query then most probably Table.words contains additional, non printable characters. Try to execute following:

```
SELECT t.words, hex(t.words), 'help', hex('help'), hex(t.words) = hex('help')
FROM Table t
WHERE words LIKE '%help%'
```

It will encode any non printable/not visible characters (white space for example) into hex. Compare hex(t.words) and hex('help'), most probably You got white space (20 in hex) or newline in front or on the end of t.words.

Comment: I find the reason, in the talbe, there is a newline at the end of the word 'help' or 'helped', and how can I write the select sentence or do something else? and i want to exact match not just like, and if there is more simple way to solve the problem

Comment: If the newline character isn't needed I would replace it by update Table SET words = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM words)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE words='help'
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE words like 'help'
```

Comment: Why is `LIKE` better for a exact match?

Comment: if use SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE words like 'help' then the result maybe help,helped,helper and I just want to return help

Comment: laiqn: No, words='help' and words like 'help' will give the same result. However, words like 'help%' will give the result you mentioned.  Álvaro G. Vicario: I guess you are right, = will always be a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `words` = 'help'
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work, thank you all the same

Answer (score 0):

Just to ask the obvious. Are you sure there is a text **'help'** in your table. If yes you can try

`SELECT * FROM table`

Then right-click 'help' from the results and copy the text and place this inside the query

`SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE words = 'copied text'`

Sometimes you might have entered an extra space without noticing or by accident (which happened to me once). Since you tried all the above answers and it did not work...this might be the problem. Hope it works.